# Someone please explain why I'm having trouble sending large byte[] to server via TCP

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, serversocket

Can someone please explain to me why `byte[] buf` on the server does not contain 100,000 1s as sent by the client? At around the 60k byte mark the values stay all zeros. I admit I haven't worked much with Streams or TCP so I'm sure I've done something wrong; I just don't understanding what it is. I've tried this with both `InputStream` and `BufferedInputStream` on the server with the same result. Thank you to anyone/everyone who can take the time to explain this to me!

Client code is pretty simple:

```
    byte[] msgBytes = new byte[100000];
    for (int i=0;i<msgBytes.length;i++){
        msgBytes[i] = 1;
    }
    Socket sck = null;
    try {
        sck = new Socket("my.server.net", 1234);
        OutputStream outStream = sck.getOutputStream();
        outStream.write(msgBytes);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            sck.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Likewise, server code is also simple:

```
    ServerSocket srvSock = new ServerSocket(1234);
    Socket sock = srvSock.accept();
    returnAddress = sock.getInetAddress();
    returnPort = sock.getPort();
    BufferedInputStream iStream = new BufferedInputStream(sock.getInputStream(), 100000);
    byte[] buf = new byte[100000];
    iStream.read(buf);
```

Comment: not sure if it is your problem, but generally you should read stream in cycle till you reach the end.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Could I trouble you for an example? How do I know it's the end?

Comment: BufferedInputStream.read(...) Returns:the total number of bytes read into the buffer, or -1 if there is no more data because the end of the stream has been reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try substituting `BufferedInputStream` with `DataInputStream` and use `readFully`, so your server code should became:

```
ServerSocket srvSock = new ServerSocket(1234);
Socket sock = srvSock.accept();
returnAddress = sock.getInetAddress();
returnPort = sock.getPort();
DataInputStream iStream = new DataInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
byte[] buf = new byte[100000];
iStream.readFully(buf);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes but anyway you need to read all the stream, you don't know size on other side. Moreover you should not read stream content to memory but better try to procces it.

```
BufferedInputStream iStream = new BufferedInputStream(sock.getInputStream(), 100000);
 byte[] buf = new byte[100000];
 int cnt;
 StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();
 while ((cnt = iStream.read(buf)) != -1) {
   content.append(buf); // you should not store content of stream, but better process it if possible
 };
```